# Get stuck while booting ubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 22.04, acpi, nvme

i got the error mentioned in the title. I never had this before but i tried every solution which is similiar to my problem in the threads

I also got this error:

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PCIO.GPPO.VGA], AE_ALREADY EXISTS (20221020/dswload-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object[\_SB.PCIO.GPPO.HDAU], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20221020/dswload2-326)
ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20221020/psobject-220)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
blacklist: Problem blacklisting hash(-13)
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean 219407/31227904 files, 4866796/124895488 blocks
```

I also tried to reinstall ubuntu 22.04 on my machine, but i got the same error after i pulled out the usb stick to reboot after install.
I also tried to move into recovery mode what also didnt work with (esc or shift) while booting.

In the past i had a dual boot with win10 and ubuntu 22.04. but then this error occured and i tried to install ubuntu 22.04 over the machine completly, but that also doenst work.

Please can anyone help me to get ubuntu running again?

Thank you very much

Comment: The message in the title of your post is not an error. It has been asked about many, many times on this site. It would be really nice if it was not displayed, because it fools lots of people with boot problems into thinking it is related to their issue, but it isn't.

Comment: thank you for your message, but the boot process doesnt go further at this point.